# Better understanding Kademlia's XOR Integer Metric

Tags: go, distributed, p2p, xor, kademlia

I'm trying to better-grasp Kademlia's XOR distance metric so I've written a small dummy program to try and understand better. I'm also not using a 160-bit number as my key here, but rather a sha256 hash of some user identifier.

Here's my xor distance function. Is this more or less correct? I'm XORing each byte– appending that to a buffer `rawBytes` and converting that  byte buffer into an integer.

```
func XorDistance(node string, otherNode string) uint64 {
    var rawBytes [32]byte
    for i := 0; i < 32; i++ {
        rawBytes[i] = node[i] ^ otherNode[i]
    }
    distance, _ := binary.Uvarint(rawBytes[:])
    return distance
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not correct because

- `binary.Uvarint()` can only decode numbers within 64 bits, and your rawBytes is 256 bits
- The "varint" encoding (as commented in https://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/varint.go) is basically not compatible with raw bytes.

You have to use the `math/big` package for usage like that. Here is my revised version of your snippet:

```
func xorDistance(node string, otherNode string) *big.Int {
    var rawBytes [32]byte
    for i := 0; i < 32; i++ {
        rawBytes[i] = node[i] ^ otherNode[i]
    }
    return big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(rawBytes[:])
}
```

Comment: Interesting– UvarInt() was actually returning a value when the two identifiers were different. Was this probably just using the first 64 bits truncated then?

Comment: @arooo I did some more research and found that `Uvarint()` (and its signed sibling) use a unique encoding described in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding (also in the source of `encoding/binary` package), which puts the least significant bits first and 7 bits of data (instead of 8) per byte. So it will give unexpected results trying to interpret arbitrary data in byte slices. Answer updated.

Comment: @arooo Also, it's recommended that you add check for length of `node` and `otherNode` and a corresponding return value of type `error` to avoid `index out of range` panics.